# R package does not load dependencies

Tags: r, import, namespaces, package

## RESOLVED

In my description file, I changed

```
Imports: dplyr (>= 0.4.3), ggplot2 (>= 2.1.0), lazyeval (>= 0.1.10)
```

to

```
Depends: dplyr (>= 0.4.3), ggplot2 (>= 2.1.0), lazyeval (>= 0.1.10)
```

This worked for me. "Imports:" may be depreciated?

---

I'm writing a package in RStudio. One of my dependencies is dplyr. When I build and reload the package, I get the following error when running a function:

```
> library(my_package)
> my_package::get_survey(...)
Error in get_survey(import_dir) : could not find function "%>%"
```

However, I've documented my dependencies in my DESCRIPTION file:

```
Imports: dplyr (>= 0.4.3), ggplot2 (>= 2.1.0), lazyeval (>= 0.1.10)
```

The libraries are installed on my system, however I want my package to work out of the box without requiring users to run

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(lazyeval)
```

before using it. How can I fix this?

Here's my sessionInfo():

```
R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices
[4] utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

other attached packages:
[1] my_package_0.0.0.9000

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.3.0
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Have you tried to put the three packages under "Depends" in your DESCRIPTON?

Comment: Yes. We may have updated at the same time.

Hadley's R Packages says "Imports:" ought to work just the same, but it appears it doesn't.

Comment: I made the same experience ...

Comment: I had the same issue. This was very helpful.

Comment: "`Imports` just loads the package, `Depends` attaches it."
http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html#namespace

Answer (score 7):

Since there's no answer yet...

J_F [writes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37568884/r-package-does-not-load-dependencies#comment62625490_37568884)

> Have you tried to put the three packages under "Depends" in your DESCRIPTON?

I ran into this recently and `Depends` still seems to work where `Imports` does not.

Comment: There is an answer. The OP was updated and marked resolved over a year ago.