# How to properly include dependencies in the DESCRIPTION file of R package?

Tags: r, r-package

I am writing an R package and here:

[R package does not load dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37568884/r-package-does-not-load-dependencies)

A user indicates that (s)he changed

```
Imports: dplyr (>= 0.4.3), ggplot2 (>= 2.1.0), lazyeval (>= 0.1.10)
```

to

```
Depends: dplyr (>= 0.4.3), ggplot2 (>= 2.1.0), lazyeval (>= 0.1.10)
```

And the problem with required packages for a new R package was solved. However, that person did not indicate if the change was done manually or by coding. I am doing the change manually and my problem persists (and I really believe the problem is about importing packages or dependencies).

My questions are:

1. Is it just fine to edit the DESCRIPTION file manually? If not,
2. Which is the proper way to do the change?

Very much thank you in advance

Comment: Edit the `DESCRIPTION` file manually.

Comment: It sounds like you've forgotten to update the NAMESPACE file, for instance using roxygen2 `@importFrom dplyr %>%` and then `devtools::document()`. It is correct to use `Import:` for packages that your package uses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer your questions:

(1) It is fine to update the `DESCRIPTION` file manually.

(2) There is no "proper way" to do this, but I find that the best way to add an R-package as an import is to use `usethis::use_package("package")`. This will add it to the correct place in the `DESCRIPTION` file, and will remind you to reference the packages you use as `package::function()` (which is needed, as the `Imports` field only load, and don't attach, the packages).

Regarding putting a package in `Depends` vs. `Imports`: you should almost always put packages your code relies on as `Imports`. You can read more about it [here](https://r-pkgs.org/namespace.html#namespace).

I hope this was useful.