# R cmd(): there is no package called ‘BiocStyle’

Tags: r, package, devtools, bioconductor

My Bioconductor package is receiving Errors about a package not existing.

I have an R package with Bioconductor. In the vignettes folder, I have several .Rmd files that have the following chunk at the top:

```
---
title: 'Manuscripts'
package: pkgName
bibliography: pkgName.bib
output:
  BiocStyle::html_document:
    toc_float: true
    tidy: TRUE
    border-width: 5px
vignette: >
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  %\VignetteIndexEntry{"Title"}
  %\VignetteEngine{knitr::rmarkdown}
  %\VignetteEncoding{UTF-8}
  %\VignettePackage{pkdName}
---
```

When I run `devtools:check()`, I receive error messages of the format:

```
   --- re-building ‘bioconductor.Rmd’ using rmarkdown
   Error: processing vignette 'bioconductor.Rmd' failed with diagnostics:
   there is no package called ‘BiocStyle’
   --- failed re-building ‘bioconductor.Rmd’
```

I noticed that `BiocStyle` is not in my `DESCRIPTION` file. So, based on instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70098615/how-to-properly-include-dependencies-in-the-description-file-of-r-package), I did:

```
usethis::use_package("BiocStyle")
```

and this seemed to add `BiocStyle,` to the "Imports" of my DESCRIPTION file. It did not add a requirement such as (>= 0.12.2).

I then reran `devtools:check()`, and received a message:

```
Warning in (function (dep_name, dep_ver = "*")  :
  Dependency package 'BiocStyle' not available.
Error: Dependency package(s) 'BiocStyle' not available.
```

I'm worried my troubleshooting may go in loops at this point. Is there something I may be missing about taking into account this particular package? I note that my package had been working on  Bioconductor for months until I suddenly received emails from the team pointing me to this error.

Thank you for any pointers you may be able to provide.

**EDIT:**

**Description file**

```
Package: pkgName
Version: pkgVerson
Title: pkgTitle
Description: pkgDescription
Authors@R: pkgAuthors
License: pkgLicense
Depends: R (>= 3.6.0)
Imports: 
    BiocStyle,
    DelayedArray (>= 0.12.2),
    dplyr (>= 0.7.2),
    GGally (>= 1.3.2),
    ggplot2 (>= 2.2.1),
    graphics (>= 3.5.0),
    grDevices (>= 3.5.0),
    grid (>= 3.5.0),
    gridExtra (>= 2.3),
    hexbin (>= 1.27.1),
    Hmisc (>= 4.0.3),
    htmlwidgets (>= 0.9),
    methods (>= 3.5.2),
    plotly (>= 4.7.1),
    plyr (>= 1.8.4),
    RColorBrewer (>= 1.1.2),
    reshape (>= 0.8.7),
    shiny (>= 1.0.5),
    shinycssloaders (>= 0.2.0),
    shinydashboard (>= 0.6.1),
    stats (>= 3.5.0),
    stringr (>= 1.3.1),
    SummarizedExperiment (>= 1.16.1),
    tidyr (>= 0.7.0),
    utils (>= 3.5.0)
VignetteBuilder: knitr
Suggests:
    BiocGenerics (>= 0.29.1),
    data.table (>= 1.11.8),
    EDASeq (>= 2.14.0),
    edgeR (>= 3.22.2),
    gtools (>= 3.5.0),
    knitr (>= 1.13),
    matrixStats (>= 0.53.1),
    rmarkdown (>= 1.10),
    roxygen2 (>=3.0.0),
    RUnit (>= 0.4.32),
    tibble (>= 1.4.2),
biocViews: Clustering, DataImport, DifferentialExpression,
    GeneExpression, MultipleComparison, Normalization,
    Preprocessing, QualityControl, RNASeq, Sequencing, Software,
    Transcription, Visualization
RoxygenNote: 7.1.1
BugReports: pkgBugs
URL: pkgURL
NeedsCompilation: no
Packaged: pkgDate
LazyData: true
Encoding: UTF-8
```

**Namespace**

```
# Generated by roxygen2: do not edit by hand

export(convertSEPair)
export(convertSESubsetGenes)
export(plotClusters)
export(plotLitre)
export(plotLitreApp)
export(plotPCP)
export(plotPCPApp)
export(plotSM)
export(plotSMApp)
export(plotVolcano)
export(plotVolcanoApp)
importFrom(DelayedArray,DelayedArray)
importFrom(GGally,ggpairs)
importFrom(GGally,wrap)
importFrom(Hmisc,cut2)
importFrom(RColorBrewer,brewer.pal)
importFrom(SummarizedExperiment,SummarizedExperiment)
importFrom(SummarizedExperiment,assay)
importFrom(SummarizedExperiment,rowData)
importFrom(dplyr,"%>%")
importFrom(dplyr,arrange)
importFrom(dplyr,filter)
importFrom(dplyr,one_of)
importFrom(dplyr,select)
importFrom(dplyr,starts_with)
importFrom(ggplot2,aes)
importFrom(ggplot2,aes_string)
importFrom(ggplot2,coord_cartesian)
importFrom(ggplot2,coord_fixed)
importFrom(ggplot2,element_text)
importFrom(ggplot2,geom_abline)
importFrom(ggplot2,geom_boxplot)
importFrom(ggplot2,geom_hex)
importFrom(ggplot2,geom_line)
importFrom(ggplot2,geom_point)
importFrom(ggplot2,geom_ribbon)
importFrom(ggplot2,ggplot)
importFrom(ggplot2,ggtitle)
importFrom(ggplot2,labs)
importFrom(ggplot2,scale_fill_gradientn)
importFrom(ggplot2,scale_fill_manual)
importFrom(ggplot2,scale_x_discrete)
importFrom(ggplot2,theme)
importFrom(ggplot2,theme_gray)
importFrom(ggplot2,xlab)
importFrom(ggplot2,xlim)
importFrom(ggplot2,ylab)
importFrom(ggplot2,ylim)
importFrom(grDevices,dev.off)
importFrom(grDevices,jpeg)
importFrom(grDevices,rainbow)
importFrom(graphics,plot)
importFrom(grid,grid.draw)
importFrom(gridExtra,arrangeGrob)
importFrom(hexbin,hcell2xy)
importFrom(hexbin,hexbin)
importFrom(htmlwidgets,onRender)
importFrom(methods,is)
importFrom(plotly,config)
importFrom(plotly,ggplotly)
importFrom(plotly,layout)
importFrom(plotly,plotlyOutput)
importFrom(plotly,renderPlotly)
importFrom(plyr,mapvalues)
importFrom(reshape,melt)
importFrom(shiny,HTML)
importFrom(shiny,actionButton)
importFrom(shiny,basicPage)
importFrom(shiny,bootstrapPage)
importFrom(shiny,br)
importFrom(shiny,div)
importFrom(shiny,em)
importFrom(shiny,fluidPage)
importFrom(shiny,img)
importFrom(shiny,numericInput)
importFrom(shiny,observeEvent)
importFrom(shiny,p)
importFrom(shiny,reactive)
importFrom(shiny,reactiveValues)
importFrom(shiny,renderPrint)
importFrom(shiny,req)
importFrom(shiny,selectInput)
importFrom(shiny,selectizeInput)
importFrom(shiny,shinyApp)
importFrom(shiny,shinyServer)
importFrom(shiny,shinyUI)
importFrom(shiny,sliderInput)
importFrom(shiny,strong)
importFrom(shiny,verbatimTextOutput)
importFrom(shinycssloaders,withSpinner)
importFrom(shinydashboard,box)
importFrom(shinydashboard,dashboardBody)
importFrom(shinydashboard,dashboardHeader)
importFrom(shinydashboard,dashboardPage)
importFrom(shinydashboard,dashboardSidebar)
importFrom(shinydashboard,menuItem)
importFrom(shinydashboard,sidebarMenu)
importFrom(shinydashboard,tabItem)
importFrom(shinydashboard,tabItems)
importFrom(stats,coef)
importFrom(stats,cutree)
importFrom(stats,dist)
importFrom(stats,hclust)
importFrom(stats,lm)
importFrom(stats,predict)
importFrom(stats,qt)
importFrom(stats,setNames)
importFrom(stringr,str_replace)
importFrom(stringr,str_trim)
importFrom(tidyr,crossing)
importFrom(tidyr,gather)
importFrom(utils,combn)
importFrom(utils,str)
importFrom(utils,write.table)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the contents of both the `DESCRIPTION` and `NAMESPACE` files.

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/a/3367)

Comment: Do you have a the line `biocViews:` in your DESCRIPTION file? You need that if you have dependencies on bioconductor packages. which `BiocStyle` seems to be. Is this package on github or something? It would be helpful to provide a reproducible example so we can run and test the checks ourselves.

Comment: Maybe need an "import_from" statement?

Comment: Thanks @r2evans, I added DESCRIPTION and NAMESPACE files.

Comment: Thank you both. I rewrote my DESCRIPTION file from what is shown above to look more like what the link @backboned suggested (i.e. to have an empty "biocViews" file after "Depends" and before "Imports". Then, when I run devtools:build(), I get the error: "ERROR: dependency ‘BiocStyle’ is not available for package ‘pkgName’"

Comment: I somehow feel it may be due to the `BiocStyle` package being called at the top of many .Rmd files within the `vignettes` folder (as shown at the top of my original post). Because I call many other Bioconductor packages, and `BiocStyle` is the only one that seems to cause the error.

Comment: If you're importing `BiocStyle`, it should be in both files, not just one.

Comment: Thanks, @r2evans. I tried to run `document()` to update my NAMESPACE file (to reflect the imported `BiocStyle` package and to hopefully see it appear in NAMESPACE too) ... but I received the error: "Dependency package(s) 'BiocStyle' not available."

Comment: If you're using roxygen2, then you need to include _somewhere_ in your package the explicit `#' @import BiocStyle` and then run `document()` in order to effect change in `NAMESPACE`. Never does it look at `DESCRIPTION` to infer imports or suggested packages.

Comment: Thanks, @r2evans. I think this is getting somewhere now. I see that all my other imported packages have `#' @importFrom pkgName methodName` in at least one of the R/.R files. However, `BiocStyle` is different, because it is *not* used in any of the R/.R files. Instead, it is only used in the vignette/.Rmd files (as shown at the top of my original post).

Comment: I tried to add `#' @import BiocStyle` to a random R/.R file (that did not use BiocStyle), then tried to run `build()` and `document()`, but received the same error for both cases ("Dependency package 'BiocStyle' not available.").

Comment: Is it possible for me to use import BiocStyle at the top of a vignette/.Rmd file (like as shown at the top of my original post)?

Comment: I don't know that roxygen2 looks there, but the fact that it has not been added suggests "no". The `'BiocStyle' not available` error suggests that you don't _currently_ have it installed, which seems odd considering I'm assuming you are otherwise using it in interactive needs. Is it in a bespoke library path (`.libPaths()`) that is not found on a vanilla (`R CMD ...`) command? (I don't use anything from bioconductor, so I'm at a loss as to why a package from that specialized repo is not "cooperating", so to speak.)

Comment: Thanks @r2evans. This is indeed a bit bizarre. I should note that my package was successfully on Bioconductor, and only recently I have started to receive messages informing me of this problem. So, it had all worked previously up until now, and I don't think it is related to whether it is installed on my personal system or on my `.libPaths()`.