# getting all dependencies of an R package when calling library

Tags: r

I have built my own R package, and I when I call library() on my package I want to also download all the dependencies while would appear in the DESCRIPTION file.

How does this work exactly? I can library on my package and I have to individually call library on some of the packages that are used in my package.

Comment: see the resolved part of this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37568884/r-package-does-not-load-dependencies?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I'm confused: you mention both *"download all dependencies"* (which should be handled with `install.packages("yourpackage")`) and then *"call library"*. In general, a package should never fully load another package into the user's environment; by including the dependent packages in the `NAMESPACE` as `import(data.table)` (e.g.) ensures that all of the functions in your package have full access to that package's functions.

Comment: If you insist on side-effect when loading your package (rarely justified imo, so far the only popular exception is `library(tidyverse)`, which despite being popular/convenient is still a problem in some areas), then see the tidyverse package for how it does it.

Comment: And the word **download** seems confusing in the xontext of your question. May be you mean that you wanted to load the dependency packages in your R session ??

Comment: Other packages are loaded based on the Description file. Any packages in the **Depends** section of the description file will be automatically loaded when your package is loaded. Most package developers prefer to use **Imports** in the description file, which makes the other packages available internally, but does not presume to load them for the user.

Comment: If I put dplyr in the imports section. Will calling library on my package load dplyr?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40391302/190277

Answer (score 4):

You can do what R does for you by relying on some public information:

```
> db <- tools::CRAN_package_db()    # a big matrix with all packages
> deps <- tools::package_dependencies("ggplot2", recursive=TRUE, db=db)
> deps                   # a list as you could have called with more than arg
$ggplot2
 [1] "digest"       "glue"         "grDevices"    "grid"         "gtable"      
 [6] "isoband"      "MASS"         "mgcv"         "rlang"        "scales"      
[11] "stats"        "tibble"       "withr"        "utils"        "methods"     
[16] "graphics"     "nlme"         "Matrix"       "splines"      "farver"      
[21] "labeling"     "lifecycle"    "munsell"      "R6"           "RColorBrewer"
[26] "viridisLite"  "fansi"        "magrittr"     "pillar"       "pkgconfig"   
[31] "vctrs"        "lattice"      "colorspace"   "cli"          "utf8"        

>
```

So by calling the `package_dependencies` (base R) function you get the list of all dependencies, either level one or fully recursively.

You could then check this with `installed.packages()` to see what if anything is missing in the local installation.